# flutter redirect to different pages on click on different kinds of notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 2 kinds of firestore triggers to send notifications to users - 1 is triggered when a new user creates a request form and 2 is triggered when a user receives a message from another user. For each case, I want to redirect users to 2 different pages on notification click.
`notifications` page for the first case, and `chatRoom` page for the second case. Here is my code, and I can't figure out how to redirect to 2 different pages based on 2 different cases. Please give me some advice.

```
  @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

  var data = message['data'];
  if (data['screen'].toString() == 'ChatClass') {
    Navigator.push(... (context) => ChatRoom()));
  } else {
    Navigator.push(... (context) => Notifications()));
  }
}, onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

  var data = message['data'];
  if (data['screen'].toString() == 'ChatClass') {
    Navigator.push(... (context) => ChatRoom()));
  } else {
    Navigator.push(... (context) => Notifications()));
  }
}, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  
  var data = message['data'];
  if (data['screen'].toString() == 'ChatClass') {
    Navigator.push(... (context) => ChatRoom()));
  } else {
    Navigator.push(...(context) => Notifications()));
  }
});
```

}

Here is my AndroidManifest file;

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myappName">
//
    
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:label="myapp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        //
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        //
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
        
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    //
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Comment: You have to simply pass data from your fireabse console to notification in json format and on this basis you can navigate the page

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Thanks Shubham. I don't understand what you mean by 'pass data from firebase console to notification in json format'. Can you give me some example, please?

Comment: Kindly please do check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is data](http://prntscr.com/xrdjsa) that you need to send from the firebase console

```
  notificationSecondCall() {
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

        // we received notification when app is in foreground 

        var data = message['data'];
        if (data['screen'].toString() == "ChatClass") {
          gotoChatRoom();  //==  your navigator method to Chat room class
        } else {
          gotoNotifications();   //==  your navigator method for Notification class
        }
      },

      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

        // we received notification when app is in background

        var data = message['data'];
        if (data['screen'].toString() == "ChatClass") {
          gotoChatRoom();  //==  your navigator method to Chat room class
        } else {
          gotoNotifications();   //==  your navigator method for Notification class
        }
      },

      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {},
    );

    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false));
  }
```

You can refer to this gist [link](https://gist.github.com/aTeamSolace/2d607b6145a7478e176dcd5f244fd0f8) for your initialize FCM data

Comment: I did it on the console and wrote your code in flutter file. When I wrote code ifor cloud functions like this `const message = {  "notification": { title: .. , body: .. }, 
        data: {click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK', screen: 'ChatClass'},` and execute the code, I have an error saying `Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You must have to select the app in your target section of firebase console

Comment: I selected the app in my target section of firebase console, and did everything you said, but I can't redirect to different pages. My app just opens where it ends last time on notification click.

Comment: @kyung please add your android manifest file in your question. second please print this value `message['data']` and check any data is getting in this variable or not

Comment: I posted my AndroidManifest file. Also, I checked my `message['data']` coming in through my app.

Comment: @kyung if you are getting `message['data']` then absolutely my answer is right. Maybe your initialization of firebase messaging is on another page. You must initialize your FCM method of `main.dart` or `splash screen page`

Comment: @kyung I have added one gist file in my answer section you can refer to this and let me know this will work for you or not

Comment: in IOS i tested, not working

Comment: hi @jancooth The answer is from last year the previous sdk now the sdk is change and the firebase methods are also changed so maybe this answer is not useful

Answer (score 2):

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage notification) {
     var data = message['data'];

     if (message.data['type'] == 'chat') {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notification', arguments: ChatArguments(notification);
     }
});
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can create some enum?

`enum NotificationType{

}`

and your notification will have one more field

`class Notification{ final NotificationType type; }`

and you can pass it from your firestore and check it?

Comment: Thanks Karen. Where should I create the enum? in flutter file, or in my cloud functions file? What notification will have one more field? in flutter file, or in my cloud functions file? Would you please elaborate more?

Comment: its some new thing for me ,so sorry for maybe bad solution,but i think you will create your enum in your flutter files ,and when in  your firestore  you make your notification you can make on more field like "notificationType:"MessageNotification"",and when your app decide to fetch your notification hi will got that field, cast it to your enum fields and check what notification for show