# How to open particular screen when scheduled local notification is shown in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, notifications, navigation, payload, flutter-local-notification

I scheduled notification locally that will appear after some time. I close the app(completely) and notification appears. I press on notification and app opens normally(same as clicking app icon goes to homepage). I would like to open a specific page not home page when clicking on a notification.

I tried sending payload when clicking on notification(if payload is "this" navigate to specific page). But I only get payload data if app is already running. Is there a way to do this. I am using flutter local navigations plugin.

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65937691/flutter-redirect-to-different-pages-on-click-on-different-kinds-of-notification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter redirect to different pages on click on different kinds of notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65937691/flutter-redirect-to-different-pages-on-click-on-different-kinds-of-notification)

Comment: This example uses firebase and push notifications. I am using local notifications.